# JQuery not validating struts2 form

Tags: jquery, struts2, validation

I am using struts2 framework for my application.
I am also using jquery validation for validating form input at client side.
however they both don't go with one another quite well.

I have the UserBean Class which I want it to be there.

I m using the following jquery & struts form.. which **does not validate the form**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var validator = $("#myform").validate({
                rules: {
                    username: "required",
                    password: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    username: "Please enter your username",
                    password: "Please enter your password"
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

---

```
 <s:form method="POST" action="doLogin" name="myform" id="myform" cssClass="form" theme="simple">
            <s:fielderror theme="simple" >

                    <label class="control-label" for="username">User Name </label>

                        <s:textfield name="userBean.userName" label="USER NAME"/>
                        <s:param>userBean.userName</s:param>



                    <label class="control-label" for="username">Password  </label>


                        <s:password name="userBean.password" label="PASSWORD" />
                        <s:param>userBean.password</s:param>

                <s:submit name="Submit" value="Submit"/>
            </s:fielderror>
        </s:form>
```

Comment: i am using these combo with like 10+ application and its working perfectly fine.i am sure problem lies with some other area.are you getting any error on firbug etc?

Comment: no error on the page as such. problem is that <s:textfield name="userBean.userName"/> is rendered as <input type="textfield" name ="userBean.userName"/> which is not picked up by the above jQuery

Comment: What is `userBean`? If `userBean.userName` is a property in a resource bundle, you have to put `<s:textfield key="userBean.userName"...` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You input names are `userBean.userName` and `userBean.password` so your script declaration must match those names in order to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var validator = $("#myform").validate({
            rules: {
                "userBean.userName": "required",
                "userBean.password": "required"
            },
            messages: {
                "userBean.userName": "Please enter your username",
                "userBean.password": "Please enter your password"
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

And as per [jQuery Validation on field(s) with a prefix in the name property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703163/jquery-validation-on-fields-with-a-prefix-in-the-name-property), you need to put the name in quotes because it contains a `.` in the name.